# Populating the db with 1M rows

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Reading on [Rails and indexing associations](http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations). The author mentions writing 1M rows of dummmy data into the db for testing performance? How did he do this? Through an each loop in the seed.rb file? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probably [loaded data from a file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). I like to use ruby to generate test data. (I don't do Rails development, but I have to do a lot of database testing.)

Answer (score 1):

Gems like [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) do a good job of generating model instances for you.  Particularly in conjunction with [ffaker](https://github.com/emmanueloga/ffaker) to give you all sorts of 'believable' test data.

You might also want to take a look at [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) for mass-importing data.  It will do bulk inserts when your database supports it (e.g. everything except for sqlite) and greatly speed them up.